# Custom code completion for class methods?

Tags: json, matlab, methods, customization, code-completion

In MATLAB, it is possible to define code suggestions and completions as explained in the documentation page titled "[Customize Code Suggestions and Completions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/customize-code-suggestions-and-completions.html#responsive_offcanvas)".

The snippets given therein, e.g.

```
{
  "_schemaVersion": "1.0.0",
  "anotherFunc":
  {
     "inputs":
     [
        {"name":"input1",  "kind":"required", "type":["numeric"]},
        {"name":"input2",  "kind":"required", "type":["numeric"]}
     ]
  }
}
```

show how we can control the predictions of functions found (presumably) in separate files in the same folder as `functionSignatures.json`.

Suppose I have a method called `myMethod` which resides in a class called `myClass`. Creating a JSON as above with `"myMethod"` instead of `"anotherFunc"` didn't seem to have an effect.

My question is - how can we define completions for **class methods** using this technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, it appears that the prediction/completion logic expects to see syntax like:

```
"myClass.myMethod"
```

In other words, this should work:

```
{
  "_schemaVersion": "1.0.0",
  "myClass.myMethod":
  {
     "inputs":
     [
        ...
     ]
  }
}
```