# Matlab code completion for class method in a class folder and namespace

Tags: matlab, code-completion

I have a class that is located in a namespace folder, and within this namespace folder it is inside a class folder. Thus, the directory structure is

```
inpath/+namespace/@ClassName/ClassName.m
```

I'd like to provide some code suggestions for a method defined in `ClassName.m`.

I have generated a `functionSignature.json` file and placed it in

```
inpath/+namespace/@ClassName/
```

which did not work, and also in

```
inpath/+namespace/
```

which didn't work either.

Furthermore, I have tried the following function names:

```
"Classname.Methodname"
```

and

```
"namespace.ClassName.MethodName"
```

in both locations, but it did not work.

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895883/custom-code-completion-for-class-methods) says that the syntax `"ClassName.MethodName"` is correct for class methods, but the class was not located in a namespace (and the answer does not say whether the class was defined in a class directory).

To be sure that there are no other errors, here is my original `functionSignature.json` file (using `"namespace.ClassName.MethodName"`):

```
{
  "SICM.SICMScan.FromFile":
  {
     "inputs":
     [
         {"name":"in1",  "kind":"ordered", "type":"file=*.sicm,*.sic,*.ras"}
     ]
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- Where to put this file in the above case?
- How to name the method?

Comment: Did you try putting it in `inpath`? I presume it is `inpath` that you added to the MATLAB path?

Comment: Uuuuuhm, of course not :(

And putting it `inpath` works, with the `"namespace.ClassName.MethodName` syntax. I should have tried this myself. But the [docs](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/customize-code-suggestions-and-completions.html) say _For MATLAB to detect the function signature information, you must place functionSignatures.json in the folder that contains the function code._ This is quite misleading...

Make an answer out of your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672806/matlab-code-completion-for-class-method-in-a-class-folder-and-namespace?noredirect=1#comment99913228_56672806) that my initial hunch is correct: the `functionSignature.json` file needs to be in whichever directory you add to the MATLAB path to use the functions. Since namespace directories are not directly added to the path, but their parent directory is, the `functionSignature.json` directory needs to be in the parent directory of the namespace directory.